# Azure Devops Server - Deploy database updates under a specific domain account

Tags: sql-server, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, sqlpackage, azure-devops-server-2019

In an on-prem/self-hosted azure pipelines release task, I want to deploy database updates via sqlpackage.exe to sql server.

I am currently doing this with a command line task.

The admins require a connection to sql server with a trusted domain account that is different from the account running the pipeline agent. The specific account will be different for different databases. (They do not allow a sql server login w/ username and password that I can give to sql package.exe)

So In an azure devops task, is there any way to run a command under a different domain account than the one the agent is running under (i.e. impersonate a different account)?

Comment: At a guess.... you might need one deploy agent per database. Which seems over the top, but I would say the requirement of a different windows account per _database_ is also a bit over the top. Also Will the admins supply you with credentials or do they want to be able to rotate / maintain them themselves? I'm not very experienced with on-prem DevOps but I assume it's very similiar to Azure DevOps

Comment: As I understand it, you can have multiple agents on one host (VM or whatever), and I _beleive_ each agent can have it's own service account (but you'll need to verify that).

Comment: I see... It's probably not a different windows account per individual database, but probably segmented by different groups of applications and environment, e.g. APPGROUP1_TEST, APPGROUP1_PROD etc.

Comment: It would make sense to have an agent per application group with its own windows account then you pick the agent at deploy time.

Comment: So is there no way to have the agent run sqldeploy impersonating another user?